# What is the difference between defining values in Lists as an overload and defining them outside of an overload?

Tags: c#

I am working on a practice exercise for C# and my way of assigning values inside a List is different from the solution code. (I am relatively new to programming so I apologize if my terminology is not accurate.) This is my code:

```
//Displays how many vowels are in the string the user inputed

Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

var vowels = new List<char>() { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
var vowelCount = 0;
foreach (var character in input)
{
    if (vowels.Contains(character))
    {
        vowelCount++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(vowelCount);

//Keep console open until user presses key
Console.ReadKey();
```

The only difference between this and the solution code are how the characters are assigned to the List:

```
var vowels = new List<char>(new char[] {'a', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'i'});
```

Why would you use `new char[] {...}` as an overload and not just simply assign the characters like the method I used?

Comment: The idiom where you pass an array (`new char[] ...`) to the constructor dates from the carboniferous era of C#. The idiom you used is called a "collection initializer" and is a more recent addition to the language. Your method is preferred these days, but either will work. If your instructor prefers the old way, do it the old way in your assignments, but continue using the modern idiom in your own code.

Comment: I think what he meant is the constructor overload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you wouldn't. Currently that overload is useful only if you have an actual array "in your hand" and want to turn it into a List. Your method of initializing is called a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) and in reality it's just a neat shorthand for a chain of `Add` calls. It leads to more concise code and also avoids the array allocation.